# Requesting tags for "Waves" game

Tags: discussion, tags

*I'm not sure at all if I am requesting tags correctly. If not, let me know it.*

Yesterday I couldn't publish a question in Arqade because there weren't tags for the game in question.

I would like to request tags for the following games:

- Waves
- Waves²
- Waves: Arena Tactics

Comment: Tags can't exist without questions, so we can't create them in preparation for questions. If you have a question for a game that does not yet have a tag, and you do not yet have sufficient reputation to create a tag yourself - just tag the questions with the game's platform (PC/XBox/WiiU/etc), and make sure to note the game's name somewhere in the question and leave a note that the tag doesn't exist yet. A helpful member of the community will sort it out before too long.

Comment: How many reputation I need for creating a new tag?

Comment: [At 300 reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @spund3 - Just make it clear in the title/body what the game is, and tag with anything, like say the platform (ps3, xbox, pc etc), and request in the comments that someone edit and create the tag for you :)